# Call a function and her params in other params function

Tags: c#

I'm trying to do this.

```
void Test(int num)
{

}

Function(Test(1)); //Error
```

How write my function to allow this ?
I'm tried this but it doesn't work.

```
void Function(Action<int> action);
```

It only work if I don't precise the integer like this.

```
Function(Test); //Compile but I can't precise the integer
```

Thank you

Comment: `Function((_)=>Test(1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How write my function to allow this ?

Change the definition of *Function* as

```
void Function(Action action);
```

Now, you can call it

```
Function(()=>Test(1))
```

If you can not change the defintion of *Function* you can call it as

```
Function((_)=>Test(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

This `Function(Test(1));` Isn't a valid C# syntax, using `()` is basically invoking the function, not passing it.
You can only do that when the function is expecting a type, and that function is return it.

> **Func and Action, Are a pre-defined delegetes that you can use without defining your own.**

Like this :

```
public static void Test(int i)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Test()");
}

public static int GetNumber()
{
    return 5;
}
Test(GetNumber());
```

If you want to pass a function to another function, there are numerous ways of doing it, Depends on if the function requires parameters or not, if it has a return type or not.

---

---

> **One parameter and no return type**

```
public static void PrintNumber(int num)
{
    Console.WriteLine(num);
}
public static void Function(Action<int> predicate, int param)
{
    predicate(param);
}
Function(PrintNumber,5);
```

---

---

> **One parameter and a return type**

```
public static int Test(int num)
{
   return num  ;
}
public static void Function(Func<int,int> predicate, int param)
{
    predicate(param);
}
Function(Test, 5);
```

The first int of this `Func<int,int>` is the parameter type, you have can up to 15 i think plus one which is the last one which is the return type.

From here you can google the rest, Hope this helps :)